# Error 400 Bad Request AJAX (WCF)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, wcf

I'm trying to use "POST" Methods in WCF but I can't use it, the only thing that I can use in my WCF service is "GET" Methods but the issues start when I try to use "POST" Methods sending Objects:

**Here you have my contract**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface Itest
{
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    [OperationContract]
    string Hello();

    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare )]
    [OperationContract]
    void AddObject(Person p);

    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    [OperationContract]
    string TurnBack(string Name);
}
```

**My Object:**

```
namespace Mywcf
{ 
    [DataContract] 
    public class Person 
    { 
        [DataMember] 
        public string Name { get; set; } 
    } 
}
```

**My implementation:**

```
namespace Mywcf 
{ 
    public class Implementacion : Itest 
    { 
        public string Hello() 
        { 
            return "Hi"; 
        }

        public void AddObject(Person p)
        {
            string Name = p.Name;
            TurnBack(Name);
        }

        public string TurnBack(string Name) 
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
}
```

**My .ASPX (Including my scripts):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <!--This SCRIPT Use my WCF as a 'GET'Method and works really good-->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#btnHi").click(function() {
                Hello();
            });
        });

        function Hello() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:83/Mywcf/Service.svc/Hello",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "{}",
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; utf-8",
                success: function(msg) {
                    try {
                        alert(msg);
                    } catch (Exception) {}
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert("Error " + result.status + '' + result.statusText);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <!--This SCRIPT has many issues (404 BAD REQUEST )I use the WCF as a 'POST' Method-->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#btnConfirm").click(function() {
                var name = $('#txtTest').val();
                Insert(name);
            });
        });

        function Insert(name) {
            var objectPerson = {
                "Name": name
            };
            var stringJ = JSON.stringify(objectPerson);
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:83/Mywcf/Service.svc/AddObject",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "{'p':" + stringJ + "}",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; utf-8",
                success: function(msg) {
                    try {
                        alert(msg);
                    } catch (Exception) {
                        alert(Exception);
                    }
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert("Error " + result.status + '' + result.statusText);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <title>TESTING WCF</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" id="btnHi" value="Hello" /> <br />
    <input type="text" id="txtTest" placeholder="Tip a Name" />
    <input type="button" id="btnConfirm" value="Ok" />
</body>
</html>
```

I think that the problem is in the headers inside the contract or when I call the AJAX.

Comment: I have 404 ERROR who said:
"400 BAD REQUEST"

Comment: WCF is not the best idea for services that are called through REST by clients like Javascript. You should be using a more specialized framework like ASP.NET Web Api for this.

Comment: The problem here is that I'm studying Software Programming and professors want it using WCF... they didn't allow Web Api for this project...
#WhatAShame

Comment: Have your code fixed - `"application/json; utf-8"` must be `"application/json; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: That's RIGHT it's working!!! Thank U so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is wrong way of appending json data.

```
 data: "{'p':" + stringJ + "}",
```

just ignore p as pass it or concatenate json stringify in a proper way.

```
function Insert(name) {
            var objectPerson = {
                "Name": name
            };
           // var stringJ = JSON.stringify(objectPerson);
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:83/Mywcf/Service.svc/AddObject",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(objectPerson),
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; utf-8",
                success: function(msg) {
                    try {
                        alert(msg);
                    } catch (Exception) {
                        alert(Exception);
                    }
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert("Error " + result.status + '' + result.statusText);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: I'm trying since I posted this... and is not working :(
I think It's a problem with my contracts... Can you do a big effort for me?
I'm really tired

Comment: is debugger hit at service side when you call this method?

Comment: No..Did you see how I have decorated data that is input name..?.

Comment: Check it out my reply above this